How to ignore lines of code from coverage in vitest?
I have my unit tests setup with vitest and I am looking for a way to ignore specific lines of code from vitest coverage.
Looking for something similar to /* istanbul ignore next */.
Is there something available for vitest?
I skimmed through the docs and tried googling. Found the solution for jest but not vitest.

Finally, /* v8 ignore next */ worked.
Using coverage-v8 for coverage.
Also, there are more ways as describe in docs
Thanks to @Gab
ignoring the next N lines
const myVariable = 99
/* v8 ignore next 3 */
if (process.platform === 'win32') {
  console.info('hello world')
}

ignoring all lines until told
/* v8 ignore start */
function dontMindMe() {
  // ...
}
/* v8 ignore stop */

ignoring the same line as the comment
const myVariable = 99
const os = process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'OSXy' /* v8 ignore next */ : 'Windowsy' 


It depends if you are using instanbul or v8 to provide the coverage of your code (default is v8) (See coverage providers documentation).
You can see the official documentation by Vitest in their link.
Basically, for v8 you can use
/* v8 ignore next */

as well as other described in their documentation like
/* v8 ignore start */

ignored_code()

/* v8 ignore stop */


For Vue templates do:
<!-- /* v8 ignore next 5 */ -->
<template>
  <div v-if="someProp">
    {{ someProp }}
  </div>
</template>

In case you happen to run into this coverage bug:

https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-vue/issues/368

